# Remove null values from SSIS package export from DB source to csv

Tags: ssis

I setup a SSIS package to export a view from multiple tables that gives me 3 columns, columnA ColumnB ColumnC to a single CSV file that contains only ColumnB and ColumnC. So it is a OLEDB source to flat file destination. I am now trying to remove rows that have a blank entry in ColumnB. I cant seem to find anything that clearly shows how to remove those rows that have a null value in columnB; coming from a DB source to flatfile destination. Anyone have any links or thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataflow, you can include a `Conditional Split` component to move the rows with an empty entry in that column to its own output, and simply ignore that output in the rest of your flow.